# Different SHAs for same commit after filter-branch, when I merge to dev or master wouldn't it fail? How can I prevent this?

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-filter-branch

I accidentally added a large file to a git repo on a specific branch and had to change the commit history for the branch to remove the file with:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD
```

Now I see different SHAs for the commits on the branch I ran the command, which I am fine with, as the repo is fairly new and only I use it currently. But, when I checked the master branch and the other dev branch, I see the SHAs for the same commit are different. When I do a merge to dev or master (which I didn't do yet) wouldn't it fail? How can I rectify this issue?

The series of git commands that were executed:

```
git checkout -b move_branch master

add files from location1 commit
add files from location2 commit
add files from location3 commit
merge the master branch of an older repo which was added as a remote   introducing some files including the big file commit 

git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD

add files from location5 commit
add files from location6 commit


A--B--C                             master
        \
X--Y--Z--A--B--C--D--E              move_branch (Z is the commit with  big file)

X--Y--I--J--K--L--M--N              move_branch (after filter-branch)
```

Comment: They are not “the same commit”. That is why the SHA is different. And why and how would the merge “fail”?

Comment: Were you on the master branch when you removed the commits?

Comment: Thanks for the update @Greg Burghardt; I wasn't on the master branch when I removed the commits. Maybe I am missing something here; but the commit that is related to the big file is not in master. I created a new branch off of master yesterday, and this is the branch where I added the commit related to the big file. So, master doesn't have that commit. I don't want yet to bring over all the commits from the new branch to the master also (would want my team members to review the new branch before I do that); only the new commit SHAs corresponding to the ones on master to appear there.

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact sequence of git commands you performed?

Comment: @GregBurghardt, updated the answer with the commands used. Thanks for your keenness to help out.

Comment: I'll look at this more tomorrow, but you can drop commits using an interactive rebase.

Comment: @GregBurghardt, were you able to come up with something to resolve the issue I am having?

Answer (score 4):

Merging your branch into master will not fail. It will also not get rid of the large file. You will actually need to run this command on the master branch and force-push this change. Since this rewrites the history of your repository, you will need to communicate and plan this with your team first. **This is a destructive action.**

**If you alone are working on this repository:**

This is the easy case. Just do a hard reset on master to the new commits.

```
git checkout -b fix_commits master
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD
git checkout master
git reset --hard fix_commits

# Push master if you need to
git push origin HEAD --force
```

---

**If multiple people work on this repo**

Your best course of action is:

1. Create a new branch from the current master branch, and push it.

   ```
   git checkout -b master_before_file_purge
   git push origin -u HEAD
   ```
2. Create a new branch to purge the large file, and rewrite its history. Push this branch.

   ```
   git checkout -b purge_large_files master
   git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path_to_file" HEAD
   git push origin -u HEAD
   ```
3. Work with each teammate individually to rebase their private trees onto `purge_large_files`
4. Work with the team to rebase shared branches that are based on master onto `purge_large_files` (you will likely need to `git push origin HEAD --force` on those branches)
5. Do a hard reset on master to `purge_large_files`:

   ```
   git checkout master
   git reset --hard purge_large_files
   git push origin HEAD --force
   ```
6. Work with teammates to make sure they can pull master without any troubles.
7. When time has gone by, delete the "before" branch:

   ```
   git checkout master_before_file_purge
   git push origin --delete master_before_file_purge
   ```

You and your teammates will need to run `git gc` locally to purge those orphaned commit objects after they pull from origin again.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Actually, I was on a different branch when the large file was introduced and I got rid of the file while on that branch (with filter-branch). The master branch doesn't have a commit that includes that file. So, I wouldn't need to worry about purging the file from master, right? Also, I didn't try merging this branch to master yet.

Comment: Also, currently, I am the only one using the repo (my team will use it, only in a couple of days). This happened while I was merging a different repo (an old repo on my local machine) to the repo in question.

Comment: @c00der: If you are the only one using the repo, just do a force push on the branch. Keep it simple. Do a hard reset if need be and a force push.

Comment: Thanks. I can do that. Is there a way for the master branch to refer to the new commit SHAs without a merge? Basically, the HEAD of master will point to the same commit as before, but the SHAs for the branch will reflect what's on the purge_large_files branch. That way, I can merge the purge_large_files branchlater to the master after my other team members are notified about the repo and they review the branch.